# Как сделать вывод записей с разными значениями используя оператор `WHERE`?

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица с полем `type`, данное поле может содержать разные значения: 1,2,3,4,... (пример).
Сделать вывод всех строк со значением типа 4 не сложно:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 4;
```

Как сделать вывод всех записей с разными типами, используя оператор `WHERE`?

Запись типа `SELECT * FROM table;` очевидно не подходит!

Comment: `where type=type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще один вариант:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE type IN (
    SELECT type
    FROM table
)
```

Хотя не могу придумать ситуацию, когда этот вариант может пригодиться в отличие, например, от упомянутого ранее `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type in (1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 4):

а так

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type in (1,2,3,4)
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type >=1 and type <= 4
```

Для особых эстетов можно использовать UNION

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

если обязательно нужна директива `where`, то можно, например, так:

```
select * from table where 0 = 0;

select * from table where true;

select * from table where type = type;

select * from table where type < 0 or true;
```

Comment: обязательно нужно, чтобы в дерективе where учавствовал type

Comment: добавил type в select.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IS NOT NULL;
```